# Markdown-to-HTML conversion on Github pages ignores backgrounds for fenced code examples

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am a first-time Github Pages designer.  I have a large number of .md files which display beautifully in a Markdown editor, but when converted to HTML, none of the fenced code blocks have the gray background

```cpp
like you see here
```

They are clearly recognized as code blocks (they use fixed-width fonts) -- but they all appear on a normal white background.

I am currently using a vanilla config file:

```
name: RTcmix
markdown: GFM
kramdown:
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
    input: GFM
```

Something I need to add/change in my configuration?  Known bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to add the following to whichever "global" css file your other files pull in for configuration:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

In my case, that was added to /css/ref.css, which was in turn referenced by /_layouts/ref.html as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ref.css">
```